# JSPM Split Code Into Multiple Bundles For Async Loading

Tags: angular, webpack, systemjs, jspm

Are there any examples of jspm where I can bundle my angular2 app into different code bundles and load the secondary bundles async.

Webpack has the concept of code splitting. I am looking for something similar to this.